# META-INF manifest is discarded on ducplication

Tags: sbt-assembly

```
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\INDEX.LIST' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
```

I'm trying to use sbt-assembly to assemble a project. I already have a jar file in my project that has `META-INF` folder and `MANIFEST.MF` file! sbt-assembly very smartly opt to discard conflict `MANIFEST` which is of course very nice. However, I don't want other people to use `-classpath` and have to type in main class each time, so I want to add my own `MANIFEST.MF` file and tell sbt-assembly to generate a right one.

How can I do that?? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want other people to use -classpath and have to type in main class each time

Here's from the readme:

> To set an explicit main class,

```scala
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.example.Main")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering :) I already set up this mainClass. This is NOT the problem. The problem is that I have a duplicated MANIFEST file in a third-party jar, so sbt-assembly is not creating my own `MANIFEST` file!

Comment: ok. If the above doesn't work when the jar from library dependency has its own MANIFEST, please open a Github issue.

Comment: I had this issue (setting mainClass seemed to have no effect) when using sbt-assembly 0.13.0, and it went away when I upgraded to 0.14.2.